# when I Added .active class to menu it not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, menu

I am trying to add `.active` class to menu in my php website using javascript but the problem that when I click on the link, it adds `.active` for very very short time and after that it remove it

```
      $(document).ready(function(){$(document).on('click','ul li a',function(){  $('li a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
 }); });
```

and code for menu is

```
<ul class="nav ls navbar-nav ">
 <li><a href="<?php echo SITE ?>contact_us.php" class="active">İletişim</a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php echo SITE ?>gallery.php">gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Is your page getting reloaded after navigation click?

Comment: That's because clicking the link causes page navigation (i.e., reloads the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript only affects what is currently on the page. If you use jQuery "addClass", when you reload the page, then the entire HTML will reset, and the .active class will be lost.

Instead of JavaScript, you must use PHP on the back-end to detect what page the browser is currently on. The below code, keeps the jQuery you want (even though it is not necessary), but also uses PHP function "create_nav_link" to detect what page you are currently on, and adds 'class="active"' to the links.

*The entire <script> section below can be removed, and the code will still work.*

Try to copy & paste the following, and please feel free to ask me questions in comments:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a {
            color : #000;
        }

        a.active {
            color : #F00;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav ls navbar-nav ">
    <li><?php create_nav_link('/contact_us.php','İletişim') ; ?></li>
    <li><?php create_nav_link('/gallery.php','gallery') ; ?></li>
</ul>
<?php

    function create_nav_link($url,$label) {

        echo '<a href="' . $url . '"' ;
        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $url ) echo ' class="active"' ;
        echo '>' . $label . '</a></li>' ;

    }

?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'ul li a', function () {
            $('li a').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the link, the URL changes (i.e. page reloads) and the HTML resets -> so, you lose the .active class.

Try this:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','ul li a',function(){
            $('li a').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            // without this below, the click on the link changes
            // the page, so the HTML gets reset
            return false ;
        })
    }) ;

</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help at now the .active class added but the page not loaded I mean when i click on link the page not loaded

Comment: @MuhammadKhaled I am guessing you want the new page to open, and the .active class to stay -> is this correct?

Comment: @MuhammadKhaled understood, working on the code now, should be ready in 5 mins

Comment: @MuhammadKhaled just added the new code as a new answer below. copy&paste the code to a new .php file, and feel free to ask me questions if parts dont make sense to you.

Comment: @sammysaglam where did you add fix for page reload? I used the above code and it added the class but page didn't reload

Comment: @i_am_beginner i believe you are looking for the `return false` above — that will prevent page reload. if you want the page to reload then remove the `return false`

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem and was using this code(Wrong Way which didn't work):

```
<li class="nav-item @if(request()->url() == route('admin.dashboard')){{'active'}} @endif">
  <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url('/admin') }}">
                    <span data-feather="home"></span>
                    Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Then I applied the `active` class on `<a>` tag rather then `<li>` and it worked for me (Code that worked for me):

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link @if(request()->url() == route('admin.dashboard')){{'active'}} @endif" href="{{ url('/admin') }}">
                    <span data-feather="home"></span>
                    Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I read the link
 [Problem with the menu and "active" class](https:////forum.getkirby.com/t/problem-with-the-menu-and-active-class/1176/3)

and that article said that we should not use `active` class with `<a>` instead with `<li>` but in my case the opposite worked and I still don't know why..